# Possible Paths across a Rectangular Grid

Tags: javascript, php

Consider a rectangular grid of 4×3 with lower  left corner named as A and upper right corner named B. Suppose that starting point is A and you can move one step up(U) or one step right(R) only. This is continued until B is reached.

[image]

1. How many different paths from A to B possible ?
2. calculate best path according to possible combinations?
3. how to implement php and javascript?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform

Comment: Think of it in terms of recursion. Break it down into smaller problem. So if you know the number of ways to get to the diagonally opposite point in a square of side 1. You can extend it to larger sizes.